# webapp2: regex in routing

Tags: python, regex, webapp2

I have such a problem: I want one method of the class to handle different URIs (for URI "/solution/add" and "solution/edit"). So I wrote such routing:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([webapp2.Route(r'/solutions/(add|edit)', handler='solution.SolutionPage:add_edit_solution'), ], debug=True)
```

And webapp2 gives 404 error. Could you please suggest the solution of this problem?

Ofcourse I can write different routes for every URI, but it's not so interesting.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [webapp2 docs](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#the-url-template) indicate,  you have to put the regex in angle brackets, with a colon separating name and expression. The name is optional, but

> everything outside of <> is not interpreted as a regular expression to be matched

So something like this: `'/blog/<:\d{4}>/<:\d{2}>'` Or in your case, this:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/solutions/<:(add|edit)>',
              handler='solution.SolutionPage:add_edit_solution')
```

Comment: It gives an error:
TypeError: add_edit_solution() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given).

I think this error occurs because this expression is for getting arguments (like "product_id" etc.).

Comment: @Dimitry, correct. What's the problem? When you pass a regex to `Route`, it calls the handler with the groups from the regex as positional arguments, or as keyword arguments if you give them names. "[The name, if defined](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#the-url-template), is used to build URLs for the route. When it is set, the value of the matched regular expression is passed as keyword argument to the handler. Otherwise it is passed as positional argument." So if you want to use a regex here, you have to pass a handler that accepts *args or **kwargs. Period.

Comment: Well, yeah) It works. Thank you. At the beginning I thought in different way to implement this, I wanted implement this without any arguments, but as I see now using arguments is better way.

Answer (score 0):

If I can add something.
For my own purpose, I've try to create a handler which perform a little bit similar operation, but the point is that I've used self.request.host or self.request.route instead of arguments.

Doing this, and parsing the result with a switch case or if/elif/else loop, allow me to create a class named URIHandler which is use to route any kind of request to the correct ressources (even 404/500/yyy error pages) dynamicly whithout having to rewrite or add route for each new ressources.

So I'll be interested in comparing the two method to bench them a little bit.